# Can't get the array to work in form php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox, confirmation

I have an issue with the checkboxes to get it working.
If none of the checkboxes have been selected, it gives an errormessage, this works fine!
Also the submitting of all other information.

I just want the form now to submit the checkboxes which have been checked into the confirmationemail. I now only get: array.

The contact.php

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "mukies@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Vul uw naam in aub");

$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$telephone    = check_input($_POST['telephone']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

$formCampagne = check_input($_POST['formCampagne']);
foreach($formCampagne as $option) {
  print $option."\n";
}

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Dit e-mail adres is niet juist, voer een juist e-mailadres in.");
}
/* If telephone is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/[0-9\(\)+.\- ]/s", $telephone))
{
show_error("Voer een juist telefoon nummer in");
}
/* If verification code is not valid show error message */

if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'mycode') {die('Voer aub de juiste code in, in     hoofdletters.');}

/* If no campaign mode is selected, show error message */
if(empty($formCampagne))
{
   show_error ("U heeft geen selectie gemaakt uit de campagne opties, selecteer minimaal een van de opties.");
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hi Rick,

Je hebt weer een offerte aanvraag ontvangen voor Limburg Media! :)

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Telefoon: $telephone

Offerte aanvraag?    $formCampagne

Comments: $comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<b>Gelieve de onderstaande foutmelding door te nemen om uw gegevens correct aan te leveren:</b><br />
<?php echo $myError; ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php exit();}
?> }
```

The Contact.htm where the visitor fills in his/her form:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Benodigde velden zijn <b>vetgedrukt</b>.</p>

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<p><b>Uw naam:</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
<b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<b>Telefoonnummer:</b> <input type="text" name="telephone" /></p>

<p>Welk soort campagne wilt u informatie over ?<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="sandwichborden driehoeksborden"   />sandwichborden / driehoeksborden<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="drukwerk banners"   />drukwerk / banners<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="evenementen outdoor"   />outdoor promotie / evenemente<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="internet website social media"  />internet / websites / social media  <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="artwork video"   />artwork / videopromotie    <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="promo gadgets sampling" />promoteams / gadgets / sampling    <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formCampagne[]" value="mobiele reclame reclame frames"   /> mobiele reclame / reclame frames    <br />  </p>


<p><b>Your comments:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>
<p>Validatie code: <input type="text" name="code" /><br />
Vul de tekst <b>MYCODE</b> hierboven in.   </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The thanks.htm page only contains standard text, saying, well... thank you. :)

Can anyone help me out here?

EDIT:

So this would be the correct code ?:

```
if(isset($formCampagne)) {
echo ".implode(',', $formCampagne)."; // this is the output in the confirmation mail
} else {
echo "U heeft geen selectie gemaakt uit de campagne opties, selecteer minimaal een van de opties.";
```

But where do I put it? Next to the "Offerte aanvraag?", beacuse this gives an error, as I am in the $message field already. 
Sorry I have not yet worked with a isset function yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$message = "Hi Rick,

Je hebt weer een offerte aanvraag ontvangen voor Limburg Media! :)

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Telefoon: $telephone

Offerte aanvraag?    $formCampagne

Comments: $comments

End of message
";
```

with:

```
$message = "Hi Rick,

Je hebt weer een offerte aanvraag ontvangen voor Limburg Media! :)

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Telefoon: $telephone

Offerte aanvraag?    ".implode(',', $formCampagne)."

Comments: $comments

End of message
";
```

Notice that I've changed the plain **`$formCampagne`** with **`implode(',', $formCampagne)`**, 'cause it is actually an array and you have to make it a string if you want to place it in your e-mail message.

Also notice that if none of the checkboxes are selected, `$formCampagne` will be `NULL`, so you should also check if `isset($formCampagne)`

EDIT:

in my example, `$formCampagne` should actually be `$_POST['formCampagne']`, I must admit I never used the `check_input()` function and do not really know how it behaves on arrays.

You could also try to `var_dump()` the content of both `$formCampagne` and `$_POST['formCampagne']`

Comment: If I try this, the mail contains nothing. it returns empty, even if items were selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for isset($formCampagne) if returns false, that means none of the checkbox is selected, else it will give you array of values.

Comment: I have tried this, see edit part. But I have no idea where to put it. Never worked with this function before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "Hi Rick,

Je hebt weer een offerte aanvraag ontvangen voor Limburg Media! :)

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Telefoon: $telephone

Offerte aanvraag?    $formCampagne

Comments: $comments

End of message
";
```

Instead of $formCampagne, you should try something like this:

```
$message = "Hi Rick,

Je hebt weer een offerte aanvraag ontvangen voor Limburg Media! :)

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
Telefoon: $telephone

Offerte aanvraag?    ".implode(', ', $formCampagne)."

Comments: $comments

End of message
";
```

That should give a list of all the selected checkbox values separated by commas.

Comment: If I try this, the mail contains nothing. it returns empty, even if items were selected